# CSS issue when I reduce the screen size

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have an issue in my IE. When I maximise the screen everything works good. 
When I reduce the screen size the input boxes and other div tags remain as such and these extended out of the page layout and my page looks messy.I want my input boxes and other Div tags to accomodate as per the need and do not go outside the page layout.

Example of my input box:

```
<div style="background-color:#c2d69b; 
            width: 628px; 
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            border-color: #6699CC;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;">

    <b>Keywords</b><br />
    <input id="keywords" 
           runat="server" 
           type="text" 
           size="100" 
           title="Keywords" /><br /><br />

</div>
```

Comment: Removed the Java tag - CSS has nothing to do with Java at all.

Comment: If the screen is minimized, how can you see anything?

Comment: sorry for using the word "minimise"..what i meant is if i reduce the size of the browser screen, the Divs and input boxes move out of the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed width of the `<div>` tag forces the container to have a width of 628px. Maybe you can use a percentage value (e.g. 100%) to fit the surrounding container.

In addition, your `<input>` tag has the attribute `size` that results in a fixed width. You may also try a percentage value in `style` for that tag to get a flexible width depending on the elements arround the input field.